# Inject a JavaScript to predefined pages and use page action

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Well I have a list of domains (about 10) which my chrome extension is going to interact with.

As I studied the chrome extensions documentation this needs to use `content_scripts` 
I have included these lines in the manifest.json

```
   "content_scripts": [ {
      "all_frames": true,
      "js": [ "js/main.js" ],
      "matches": [ "http://domain1.com/*",
                   "http://domain2.com/*",
                   "http://domain3.com/*",
                   "http://domain4.com/*",
                   "http://domain5.com/*",
                   "http://domain6.com/*",
                   "http://domain7.com/*",
                   "http://domain8.com/*",
                   "http://domain9.com/*",
                   "http://domain10.com/*"
      ],
      "run_at": "document_start"
   }],
```

This means that during loading every page that the url matches the defined url's in the manifest file, then the main.js will be injected to the page. Am I right? yes.

So I want to do some UI when the script is injected through `page action`

I included these lines to the manifest:

```
   "page_action": {
      "default_icon": "images/pa.png",
      "default_title": "This in one of that 10 domains, that is why I showed up!"
   },
```

It seems that it is not enough. and I have to manually trigger the page action. 
but where ?
I realized that for this purpose I would need a background.html file.

but Why I can not include the trigger at the same main.js file?
answer:

```
However, content scripts have some limitations. They **cannot**:

 - Use chrome.* APIs (except for parts of chrome.extension)
 - Use variables or functions defined by their extension's pages
 - Use variables or functions defined by web pages or by other content scripts
```

So included it in the manifest:

```
"background_page": "background.html"
```

and this is the content:

```
        <html>
          <head>
            <script>
                function check (tab_id , data , tab){
                    //test just one domain to be simple
                    if (tab.url.indexOf('domain1.com') > -1){
                        chrome.pageAction.show(tab_id);
                    };
                };
                chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(check);
            </script>
          </head>

        </html>
```

**Fair enough until here,**

What I want and **I don't know** is how to add the ability of toggle on/off the extension.

User clicks on the page action icon -> the icon changes and turns off/on (the main.js would act different)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding the content script through the manifest, you can also use the [`chrome.tabs.onUpdated`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#event-onUpdated) in conjunction with [`chrome.tabs.executeScript`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-executeScript):

```
// Example:
var url_pattern = /^http:\/\/(domain1|domain2|domain3|etc)\//i;
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if (url_pattern.test(tab.url)) {
        if (changeInfo.status === 'complete') { // Or 'loading'
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {'file':'main.js'});
            chrome.pageAction.show(tabId);
        }
    } else {
        chrome.pageAction.hide(tabId);
    }
});
```

Do not forget to check for the value `changeInfo.status`, because otherwise, the content script will be executed twice.

In one of these `if`-statements, you can incorporate a check whether the extension is active or not, and act upon it:

```
if (changeInfo.status === 'complete' && am_I_active_questionmark) ...
```

Side not: Instead of using `background_page`, you can also use `"background": {"scripts":["bg.js"]}`, and place the background script in `bg.js`.

Comment: @safaali Set the `am_I_active_questionmark` variable in the [`chrome.pageAction.onClicked.addListener`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/pageAction.html#event-onClicked) event handler.